# Onkeypress doesn't detect first character

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to remove watermark of text box on enter of first character
I have written event of key press, after enter of key it returns length of zero on first character. I tried key up, problem with key up is when some one holds continuously the key the
water mark doesn't hide:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="txtHomeSearch"  onkeyup="javascript:CheckInputLength(this,'lblwatermark')"/>

function CheckInputLength(e,labelid) {
    if (e.value.length != 0) {
        $(labelid).className = 'NewHP_LabelSearch';
        $(labelid).hide();
    }
}
```

The water mark doesn't hide on `onkeypress` event.

Please help me out

Is there any event detects the on change of text box for first character and copy paste..

Answer (score 2):

The `keypress` event happens before the key is accepted by the `<input>`. (People use this to prevent the `<input>` from accepting the event.) You want to use the `input` event, which fires after the value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

change this `onkeyup="javascript:CheckInputLength(this,'lblwatermark')"` to this `onchange="CheckInputLength(this,'#lblwatermark')"`

You needed to add in a # character in the beginning to make it a valid id selector. Also the javascript: thing is not needed so took it out.

Edit:  reread question.  It looks like poster wants the onchange event for the input